# R - Search for a currency value inside a text

Tags: r

This should be an easy one, I'm trying to validate if a given value is contained on a given string. say:

```
x <- "epsi lorem epsi lorem epsi lorem epsi lorem epsi lorem 1 000€ epsi lorem epsi lorem epsi lorem"
y <- "1000"
```

goal is to return true if y is in x.

the problem is that the currency has many formatting options (spaces, commas, dots) for both decimal and thousand separators. (side note: X is populated by reading pdf invoices with OCR) while y was a manual input from someone reading the invoice. The idea is simply to validate that the person didn't make a mistake)

One option would be to try them all with grepl:

```
grepl("1000", x) | grepl("1 000", x) | grepl("1.000", x) | grepl("1,000", x)
```

But given decimal, thousand and million separators all can vary with country/software it is not reasonable

I've also looked at

```
length(agrep(y, x, max.distance = 2))
```

but then "1000" turns into "10" and I risk getting true for something like "10 jan 2020. Value = 150€"

Comment: Do the invoices include a symbol for the currency type? Is this always constant? You might consider looking at using a regex expression. Perhaps you could provide a vector with the various permutations of currency which need to be checked for.

Comment: No, some have, others don't, and those that do might use either $ or USD for instance. But even if it did, an invoice could also have a dozen of other misleading values. I'm keeping x string short, but it very well might be 2-10 pages long with dates, bank info, values, and other text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
grepl(paste0("(?!=[0-9])", y, "(?![0-9])"), gsub("[[:space:],.]", "", x), perl = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE
```

What this is doing is removing whitespace, commas, and decimals from the original string,

```r
gsub("[[:space:],.]", "", x)
# [1] "epsiloremepsiloremepsiloremepsiloremepsilorem1000epsiloremepsiloremepsilorem"
```

then `grepl`ing (it's a real verb, honest) for your `y` number when it is not preceded or followed by a digit.

It also appears to work when `y` is the first or last component of the string:

```r
grepl(paste0("(?!=[0-9])", y, "(?![0-9])"),
      c("1000", "a1000", "1000a", "10000", "a10000", "10000a"), perl = TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much r2evans, removing those 3 characters with gsub makes the task a lot easier. Also learning about perl.
It doesn't entirely fix my problem since i'd like something like this to also work:

```
x <- "epsi 1000,00€ lorem"
y <- "1000"
```

Given that y was numeric converted to text, it won't have decimals on round numbers, but an invoice very well might.
I'll be opting for a small adaptation to that:

```
fn.catch <- function(x,y) {
    y2 <- ifelse(grepl(".", y, fixed = TRUE), y, paste0(y, ".00"))
    return(
        grepl(paste0("(?!=[0-9])", gsub("[[:space:],.]", "", y ), "(?![0-9])"), gsub("[[:space:],.]", "", x), perl = TRUE)
        |
        grepl(paste0("(?!=[0-9])", gsub("[[:space:],.]", "", y2), "(?![0-9])"), gsub("[[:space:],.]", "", x), perl = TRUE)
    )
}
```

just for reference of what the function does:
y2 variable is a copy of y with the decimals ".00" if y didn't originally have them
function will then validate if either Y or Y2 is on X
removing any `" "`, `","` or `"."` from X, Y and Y2.
`"(?!=[0-9])"` and `perl = true` will then make sure that the characters before and after the number found are not also numbers so something like "1" is not in "313"

Unfortunately it still not 100% fool proof as it won't protect me from misplaced decimals, say:

```
x <- "epsi 1234,56€ lorem" 
y <- "12345.6"
```

(will return TRUE when it clearly was a human mistake)
but I'd say it will catch nearly everything, thanks a lot @r2evans